# URL-Based-Navigation in iOS like three20's TTNavigator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

Are there any alternative for [URL-Based-Navigation](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation) like what three20's  `TTNavigator` provided?

The drawback is three20 as it is no longer maintained, so we are looking for alternative.

The URL-Based-Navigation is very handy to use, e.g.

e.g.

```
[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:
  [[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://restaurant/Chotchkie's"] 
   applyAnimated:YES]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, jverkoey, the last maintainer of three20 wrote a simple framework with url mapping for objects called sockit https://github.com/jverkoey/sockit.

Comment: trying now with ARC. Had to remove `release, autorelease, retain, dealloc` etc. Any drawback sofar?